# How can I find median values of 1 column based on values of 2 other columns using svyby in r?

Tags: r, survey

I want to find median values of a variable after grouping by two other variables in the data frame using the survey package.

This is the code I would use if I was not using the survey package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(a,b) %>%
summarise(MedianC=(median(c)))
```

I want to produce these same results, only using survey methods

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
design_df <- svydesign(ids = ~id, strata = ~strata, weights = ~weight,     data = df)

medians_c <- svyby(~c, ~a+b, design_df, svyquantile, quantiles = 0.5, ci = TRUE, vartype = "ci") %>% as_tibble()
```

If instead of ~a+b I only include a in the svyby statement, I get the median values of c for each value of a. But I need the median values of c for each combination of a and b.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. It would be nice if you could include a snippet of data for us to play around with to help you. You could create one by posting the output `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: What happens in the `~a+b` case? That should do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @tjm that sounds like a data issue. You need to share the data (or a minimally similar substitute) if you want help with that.

Comment: @merv it works great when finding svymean, but when switching to svyquantile, I get this error: _Error in approxfun(cum.w, xx[oo], method = method, f = f, yleft = min(xx), : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate_

Comment: @merv ok thank you. I will try to make a small dataset for help